# Using Vue Router in Quasar outside component only changes url but not the page itself. (In Typescript)

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-router, quasar-framework

Helper function ---->

```
import route from '../router/index';
```

Adding store here cause of TS limitations:

```
const router = route({
  store: pinia,
})

export function RoutePusher() {
    router.push({name: 'login'})
}
```

Component ------->

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { RoutePusher } from 'src/helpers/file.ts';

function ComponentMethod() {
    RoutePusher();
}
</script>
```

Router ------->

```
export default route(function (/* { store, ssrContext } */) {
  const createHistory = process.env.SERVER
    ? createMemoryHistory
    : process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE === 'history'
    ? createWebHistory
    : createWebHashHistory;

  const Router = createRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ left: 0, top: 0 }),
    routes,

    // Leave this as is and make changes in quasar.conf.js instead!
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> vueRouterMode
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> publicPath
    history: createHistory(
      process.env.MODE === 'ssr' ? void 0 : process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE
    ),
  });

  return Router;
});
```

After using the method, only url changes but not the page.
I've also tried this in my layout:

```
 <router-view :key="route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

Comment: i'm not posting it yet as an answer, but can you try `:key="$route.path"` and see if that works? it works at my project.

Answer (score 0):

#### this worked for me:

instead of

```
router.push({ name: 'login' });
```

use

```
router.push({ name: 'login' }).then(()=>{router.go()});
```